# configure Angular 2 Webpack App in Docker container environment specific

Tags: angular, nginx, docker, webpack

We want to deploy our **Angular 2** app using **Docker images** in different environments (staging/test, production, ...)

When developing locally we are connecting to the backend REST API via http://localhost:8080 but when we deploy in the different environments we want to use the **same Docker image** and connect to a **different REST API endpoint**.

What would be the preferred way to **inject** this **configuration** into the **Docker container at runtime**?

Is there a way to do this via **environment variables**?

Can we do this via a **plain text file** containing something like

```
{
    "BASE_URL": "https://api.test.example.com"
}
```

Comment: are you using angular-cli or a custom build?

Comment: we created the project based on https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/

Comment: Sorry, I am not proficient on how this is working with the werbpack-starter repo. angular-cli which we are using has the option you describe (environments).

Comment: as far as I am familiar with angular-cli those environments are used at build time and not at runtime, what we are looking for is a way to configure the app at runtime

Comment: You are right. But with your docker solution, wouldn't you build your app inside docker before running it anyway?

Comment: I would build it once inside Docker and then deploy the created image in multiple different locations. There has to be a way to configure an Angular 2 app at runtime!

Comment: Ok, got you. Sorry I am no help then.

Comment: This may do what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43234536/most-modern-way-to-externalize-angular-2-environment-configuration/43980985#43980985

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After having some discussions in this post and on twitter it looks like there is no easy way to achieve what I want via Webpack. The files are only served as static files at runtime and it is not possible to exclude a file at build time and include it at runtime.

So I decided to go with the solution/workaround I had in mind: changing the static files when starting up the docker container.

I create my docker image by doing

```
npm run build:prod
docker build -t angularapp .
```

I am using the official nginx docker image as my base image and the Dockerfile looks like

```
FROM nginx:1.11.1

COPY dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY run.sh /run.sh

CMD ["bash", "/run.sh"]
```

The `run.sh` is used to modify the config file via `sed` and to start nginx afterwards:

```
#!/bin/sh

/bin/sed -i "s|http://localhost:8080|${BASE_URL}|" /usr/share/nginx/html/api.config.chunk.js

nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

This allows me to configure the `BASE_URL` via environment variabel in my `docker-compose.yml` file (simplified):

```
version: '2'

services:
  api:
    image: restapi
  frontend:
    image: angularapp
    environment:
      BASE_URL: https://api.test.example.com
```

With this solution/workaround I can deploy the docker image created by my jenkins job for a specific version deploy in all my environments (development, staging, production) by configuring the REST API endpoint used via environment variable when starting the docker container.

Comment: I tried all the solution you have produced here but failed so can you share your code with me please. I also should do the same.

Answer (score 3):

The final solution here is completely dependency on what your CI / CD toolchain looks like but this solution can be molded into pretty much anything.

First step: Add something like https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv to your `dependencies` this will be handling your config values. There are other optiions & depending on your needs, rolling your own is easy enough.

Per the docs, load the config as early as possible in your app ( global app.module.ts is my personal choice as we want this to be globally available ).

Simply - Based on `process.env.NODE_ENV` you are going to load different configs per stack and to make the DX simple, I always give config values a default so my developers don't have to bother with the file.

For `TESTING, STAGING, PRODUCTION` - As an example, you want to set `BASE_URL_STAGING` & `BASE_URL_PRODUCTION` in the environment variables for whatever CI provider you are using.

As a part of your CI run & based on git branch, write your config values into a `.env` file and then add a `COPY` into your `Dockerfile` || `docker-compose.yml` to pull in the environment file you just wrote during your docker build.

After your validations, when you push your new docker image, the .env is part of your deployment package targeting what ever environment specific endpoints you need.

Comment: this does not lead to what I want: I want one docker image of a specific version that I can deploy to multiple environments with different configurations :(

Comment: The mechanism for passing the env variables doesn't really matter. Something like dotenv & it's associated webpack plugin just wire external environment variables to your application. You can just as easily pass something like `BASE_URL_STAGING` into your docker run command

`docker run -e ` or in your docker-compose like ..

`environment:
    - BASE_URL=${BASE_URL_FROM_ENVIRONMENT}
`

It's a two part problem. dotenv handles getting the external vars into your application, setting those vars is toolchain specific

Comment: I understand, but the important part is that I do not want to build multiple docker images for different environments (staging, production, ...). I only want to run `npm run build:prod` once and package that created files up in a docker image

Answer (score 2):

I would have taken a slightly different, but in a way similar approach to your `sed`-shellscript.

I like the idea of the "plain text config file" that you mentioned, how about this:

Serve the config file from a known location, e.g. `./config`?
Since your JS is already loaded from the current site, at least there you should be able to rely on a relative path.

Step 1: The shellscript starting up in the docker container writes the config parameters from the environment variables to the plaintext file and places it in the same folder as the packed angular code.

Step 2: In the main HTML file that loads the app there is some init code like this:

```
$(function() {
  $.get('./config')
    .then(function(res) {
      window.appConfig = res.data;
      // your bootstrapping call
      angular.bootstrap(....);
    });
});
```

Step 3: You use the global variables in your angular app, e.g. if you are using OpaqueToken:

```
import { OpaqueToken } from '@angular/core';

const CONFIG_TOKEN = new OpaqueToken('config');

export const THIRDPARTYLIBPROVIDERS = [
  { provide: CONFIG_TOKEN, useValue: window.appConfig }
];
```

Yes this is still a bit hacky & in your dev-env the node-proxy that you use for serving the ng-app also has to expose such a config endpoint.
Also this needs an additional request, but this could be easily avoided by extending the init-code a bit to cache the data in localStorage for example (given that this data won't really change over time).

But all in all I think this is a bit more maintainable than `sed`-ing some files of which you don't really know how they are layed out.

Let me know what you think!