# Angular & Docker: Environment aware configuration

Tags: angular, docker

We'recurrently setting up an SPA with Angular 4, hosting it with Docker on Azure. Usually, the environments (Prod, Development, Testing) are set in Angular with the Environment-Configs, which are compiled, if we use the Angular-CLI build command. This is great, but the workflow with Docker is a bit different:

1. Build the Angular App
2. Initialize the Docker container
3. Set the Docker Container environment variables
4. Start the Docker container

This means we have a timing problem, because on compile-time, we can't say, on which environment the App will run. For the server (.net core), this is no problem, since we can use the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable, but we didn't find a solution to make the App aware of the environment-type.
I'm almost certain we're not the only people around with this problem, yet I didn't find proper solution so far. Is there some possibility around we aren't aware of?

Comment: Did you ever see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40379931/configure-angular-2-webpack-app-in-docker-container-environment-specific)? It isn't quite your workflow (and I realise this post is quite old). Did you ever figure out how to sort your environment variables?

Comment: Unfortunately, we still have no proper solution. We created a infrastructure service, which holds these values and delivers them dependending on the Environment, but out of the box on the client side, there seems no solution.

Comment: @MatthiasMüller, this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43234536/most-modern-way-to-externalize-angular-2-environment-configuration/43980985#43980985

Comment: Cool idea, thanks, I will give it a try.

Comment: @MehradSadegh That would mean I would have to change the environment for each stage, is that correct? I think the usual goal nowadays is to test an artefact on mulitple stages without having to alter it between, or am I wrong?

Comment: @MatthiasMüller Yes, but at least your environment configurations are not in a huge minified js file. I use Bamboo which separates builds from deployments. When I run the build plan, ng build will create the assets folder containing environment.json file. In my deployment plan, I overwrite that file with the correct environment file eg. environment.staging.json. 
In your case, if you're shipping your pre-built docker containers to different environments, you can setup your docker container to use environment variables to overwrite the environment.json file before starting your web server.

Comment: @MatthiasMüller I was wondering how did you solve it in the end?

Comment: see this post for a different/smarter way to load the config at runtime using APP_INITIALIZER: https://juristr.com/blog/2018/01/ng-app-runtime-config/#runtime-configuration

Comment: @SwissCoder Thank you, we're also using AppInitializers, if the services need the configs already, (I think). I'm still baffled there is no direct support for this, since using the same artefacts for all stages is one of the main principles of release management.

Answer (score 7):

Since my main goal was to not create a Container per environment but also to keep the build process environment-agnostic, I came up with the following solution:
I'm using the docker-stack file to add a command (My Docker image is NGinx):

```
command: /bin/bash -c "cp /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/app-settings/appsettings.__EnvironmentName__.json /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/app-settings/appsettings.json && find "/usr/share/nginx/html/assets/app-settings/" -type f -name "*.json" -not -name "appsettings.json" -exec rm {} ';' && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
```

The command does three things:

1. Copy a environment specific appsettings.json (see below) as
   appsettings.json
2. Remove all appsettings.xxx.json except
   appsettings.json
3. Start nginx

The release process also replaces **EnvironmentName** with the specific environment it is deploying to. This means, each container has now an appsettings.json in place with the environment-specific data.
On the angular code, I'm using the environment-files just for compile-time, environment-agnostic, information:

`export const environment = {
  production: false
};`

The appsettings are saved as assets:

[image]

To read the runtime information of appsettings.json, I've created a appsettings provider service, using a local http call:

```
@Injectable()
export class AppSettingsProviderService {
  private appSettings: AppSettings;

  public constructor(private http: LocalHttpService) {
  }

  public async provideAppSettingsAsync(): Promise<AppSettings> {
    if (this.appSettings) {
      return Promise.resolve(this.appSettings);
    }

    // This path needs to be relative to the files in the dist-folder
    this.appSettings = await this.http.getAsync<AppSettings>('./assets/app-settings/appsettings.json');
    return this.appSettings;
  }
}
```

This works also during development, since just the appsettings.json is used in this case and even with ng serve, the code is compiled into dist, meaning the relative path is still correct.

Comment: Overall thanks for this Matthias!  I really just simplified your solution here a bit and just change the docker-compose file to copy the config needed over the appconfig.production.json file.  For example--> command: sh -c "cp /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/appconfig.staging.json /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/appconfig.production.json && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'" since we have each different config in each file. This just works perfectly!