# Angular Bootstrapping: Load Service before Modules

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal

I would like to use environment aware appsettings (my original question and answer is here: [Angular & Docker: Environment aware configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44549480/angular-docker-environment-aware-configuration/53589512#53589512)), which works great. 
Unfortunately, some modules, like MSAL, require a configuration when importing the module. For example:

```
MsalModule.forRoot({
  clientID: AppSettingsSingletonService.instance.msalConfig.clientId,
  redirectUri: AppSettingsSingletonService.instance.msalConfig.redirectUri,
})
```

You might already see the problem: I would need a service loaded to get the configuration instance, Unfortunately, I didn't find a way so far to force a load before the module is called. Trying the APP_INITIALZER also doesn't work:

```
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initApp,
      deps: [
        AppInitService
      ],
      multi: true
    },
  ],

export function initApp(appInitService: AppInitService) {
  return () => {
    return appInitService.initializeAppAsync();
  };
}
```

Since it doesn't make sense (for me) to have this data hardcoded, is there a possible way to load a service before the Modules are imported?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is in the main.ts file, fetch the configurations from where you want to.
Take the code below as an example:

```js
window.fetch('api/config')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then((resp) => {
    const msal = resp['msal'];
    const protectedResourceMap: [string, string[]][] = [
      [resp.gatewayAPIBaseUrl, [resp.gatewayApiB2CScope]]
    ];
    const msalConfig = {
      authority: msal.authority,
      authoritypr: msal.authoritypr,
      clientID: msal.clientID,
      validateAuthority: false,
      cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
      postLogoutRedirectUri: resp.applicationURL,
      navigateToLoginRequestUri: false,
      popUp: false,
      unprotectedResources: ['https://angularjs.org/', 'api/config'],
      loadFrameTimeout: 6000,
      protectedResourceMap: protectedResourceMap,
      redirectUri: resp.applicationURL
    };

    window['appSettings'] = resp;

    platformBrowserDynamic([{
        provide: MSAL_CONFIG,
        useValue: msalConfig
      }]).bootstrapModule(AppModule)
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  })
```

Here, I set api/config as unprotected resources to prevent HTTPInterceptor from complaining about it not being registered in B2C

So I fetch the config before hand from AppSettings and build the MSAL config before MSALService and MSALModule look for it

my app.module.ts now looks like this:

```js
imports: [
    ...
    MsalModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    MsalService,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MSALHttpinterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
```

Hope this answers