# Angular 2 - angular-cli: set global variable on build

Tags: angular, angular-cli

This is my first time trying to deploy an Angular2 application.  I want to set the URL of an API endpoint, and I would like for it to be different in every environment.

Is there a way to make ng build or any other tools that would allow set this for me prior to deployment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the Angular CLI tool you can configure different environments.

`ng build` can specify both a build target (`--target=production` or `--target=development`) and an **environment file** to be used with that build (`--environment=dev` or `--environment=prod`). By default, the development build target and environment are used.

The mapping used to determine which environment file is used can be found in angular-cli.json:

```
"apps": {
  "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
  "environments": {
    "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
  }
}
```

These options also apply to the serve command. If you do not pass a value for environment, it will default to **dev** for development and **prod** for production.

You can also add your own env files other than **dev** and **prod**.

Then, in your code, you can do a simple check, just like the default one in the main.ts file:

```
if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}
```

Check out the [build targets and environment files](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#build-targets-and-environment-files) section in their docs for more details.

PS: [Here's a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36004810/how-to-config-different-development-environment-in-angular-2-app), you might find the answers there useful too.

Comment: Mersi bratle.

How can I reference the environment from a .ts file such as a service? I am getting "environment is not defined". Is there a special way to import it?

Comment: Hm, you must have missed a step. 1) Check if you have the `"environments": {
  "source": "environments/environment.ts",
  "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
  "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
}` in your `angular-cli.json`. 2) Check if you have the files in your `src/environments/` directory. 3) Do you run the `ng build` with a `--environment=dev` flag? 4) Check if your environment.ts file actually exports the constant: `export const environment = { production: false };`



PS: Molq bratle :)

Comment: 5) Check if you are missing the import statement in the place you're using it: `import { environment } from './environments/environment';`

Answer (score 7):

Yes, and it's actually quite convenient. Take a look at the `src/environments/` directory. You have there at least 2 files, one of which is `environment.ts`. **Do not change this one**. Instead you should put your different env-related configs in other files in this directory, e.g. `environment.prod.ts`.

Everything is nicely explained in the comment put in `src/environments/environment.ts`:

> The file contents for the current environment will overwrite these during build.
>
> The build system defaults to the dev environment which uses `environment.ts`, but if you do
>
> `ng build --env=prod` then `environment.prod.ts` will be used instead.
>
> The list of which env maps to which file can be found in `angular-cli.json`.

So you just have to import the const defined in that file using a normal typescript import, e.g.

```
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
```

Then you can set it up in the service:

```
@Injectable()
export class SettingsService {
    public environment = environment;
}
```

and now you inject use such service in other places, like any other service ;)

Comment: How can I reference the environment from a .ts file such as a service?  I am getting "environment is not defined".  Is there a special way to import it?

Comment: What is the advantage of mediating the environment through a service, instead of just accessing it directly from wherever I need it?

Comment: I think it can have a value for unit testing: in this setup you can easily change values by mocking a service (instead of e.g. providing additional environment for this) - you can then run your tests against different "env" values etc.