# asp.net core <environment> equivalent in angular2?

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core

In asp.net core, I can conditionally include css/js in my layout html page using `<environment>` tags:

```html
<environment names="Development,Staging">
    <script type="text/javascript" href="js/debug.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</environment>

<environment names="Production">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.min.css" />
</environment>
```

How can I achieve this in angular 2? The css/js files that I'm talking about are site-wide, not component-specific

(PS. **I'm new to angular 2**)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36004810/how-to-config-different-development-environment-in-angular-2-app

Comment: @TheDictator I'm new to angular 2, I'm not sure I can do this since meta tags are outside the scope of traditional angular binding???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using angular2 CLI then you could use `enironment.ts`.
Properties specified in this file will be available throughout entire application.

You can create multiple environments like this-

[image]

In components import default environment file like this-

```
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
```

Import DOCUMENT from platform-browser like this-

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

Inject into component (e.g. main AppComponent),

```
constructor (@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document) { }
```

Use environment condition and apply dynamic style-sheet like this-

```
if(environment.EnvName === 'prod') {
        this.document.getElementById('theme').setAttribute('href', 'prod.css');
}
else {
        this.document.getElementById('theme').setAttribute('href', 'dev.css');
}
```

Angular CLI takes care of which file to use for each environment during build process.

This is how you can specify environment at a time build-

```
ng build --env=prod
```

Hope this helps in your use case.

Comment: This is great but what if you have more environments and, by extension, different variables per environment. You will need to pre build each environment and deploy them all together, then switch between SourcePaths based on the environment?