# How to hide enviroment variables from public code in angular 2?

Tags: angular

I have my const variables in **env.dev.ts**.

```
export const ABC_BASE_URL = "http://api.me/api/v1/";
export const TOKEN = "current-token'";

export const LOGIN = "auth";
export const LOGIN_URL = ABC_BASE_URL + LOGIN;
export const LOGIN_ENABLE = true;
```

I have this file inside **src/app** so I can see it on the browser.
Then I read on [config different enviroments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36004810/how-to-config-different-development-environment-in-angular-2-app) that it was a bad practice to:

> exposes the internals of your development environment publicly.

Im **not** using *angular-cli*.

So, how should I do it? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no real way you can hide the details of code/data in Javascript in the client browser. You can probably try to encrypt and decrypt using any utility available in the market. Also as a suggestion instead of hard coding the values in the files, write an API which gives you these details for only authenticated users, even this will not completely solve the problem, but at least decreases the risk of a person able to copy it simply from you file.