# How to specify custom environment variables in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I would like to use another environment variable. In my case `test`. The reason is that I want to inject a http interceptor for my integration tests. This interceptor should only return a mocked response with predefined data and is used for testing only.

Is there an official angular-way?

So simply I want this `app.module.ts`:

```typescript
    import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
    // ...

    export function CustomHttpProvider (backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) {
      return new HttpService(backend, options);
    }

    export function FakeHttpProvider (backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) {
      return new FakeHttpService(backend, options);
    }

    const HttpProvider = environment.test ? FakeHttpProvider : CustomHttpProvider;

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,

        // ... my modules + routing here
      ],
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: Http,
          useFactory: HttpProvider,
          deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
        }
      ],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular CLI has a command line parameter  --environment that will let you do this if you set up some class to support that.

See this [blog post](http://tattoocoder.com/angular-cli-using-the-environment-option/)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36004810/how-to-config-different-development-environment-in-angular-2-app) provides lots of information related to your question.

As a side note. For angular 1.5 I have used [this plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-environment).

Comment: I missed to add the `environment.test.ts` file under `environments` in `angular-cli.json`. The link to the blog post shows more infos about that. Thanks for your answer ;-)